# Tool to merge 3 CSS files

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css

Merging huge CSS files is huge pain,

Hi i found some question asked on the same line. I tried some of the tools but they end up merging line by line rather than on the basis or CSS rules.

Now i thought i should right one good program to do following,
1. read CSS file convert in XML
2. sort it on the basis of CSS rule

Now write one more program to consume 3 XML files find different classes and merge the files nicely based on CSS rules.

How ever that turned out to be good amount of work and i hope there must be someone who must have faced this problem before me and solved it clean way.

Please add your thoughts and suggestions, I would love to know the tool for this however i would also love to know how to design/code for this kind of tool? Am i thinking on right track ?

Thanks All,

Comment: Instead of merging them, you can also consider including them all and they will cascade on top of eachother. In CSS, the last rule always takes precedence.

Comment: Yes that can be done but if the CSS are huge .. say 3 files each of size 100 KB. Then i am putting 300KB which will be downloaded on each users machine which makes it bad.

Comment: Hmmm. In my mind, the best instance to produce "merged" CSS is the browser, as its computed style is *exactly* what of the existing rules is being parsed. Firebug can display computed style but only for one element at a time. Maybe a Firefox Extension exists? A quick search turned up nothing but maybe worth some investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a free tool called CSS Merge](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/combine-merge-multiple-css-files/).  Have you tried it?

Comment: I was wondering if this solution was still available to the general public here in 2015? It seems as if I am currently unable to install this program, or possibly it is not accessible online?

I get this message:  An error occurred trying to download 'http://www.cssmerge.com/CSS Merge.application'.

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDA7B8.tmp\install.log' for more information.

Comment: Uh, cssmerge.com is not the site I linked to.  I'm not sure how you got to that host.

Answer (score 0):

Since order is important in CSS, it is difficult to merge files more sensibly than simply concatenating them. Certainly, this can't be done in the general case. In a specific case you might be able to produce a tool that can do it.