# Ways to Combine CSS

Tags: css

I have multiple CSS files (the designer made several, *bad* iterations) that I need to combine to a single file. However, I don't want to just cat them together. I want to merge the properties for like selectors, ie:

```
file 1
#mainmenu {width:100%; background:#01568b; text-decoration: none; }

file 2
#mainmenu {width:100%; background:#01568b;}
```

Where the output would be

```
#mainmenu {width:100%; background:#01568b; text-decoration: none;}
```

obviously, this is a simple example, but should explain what I'm looking to do. Are there any tools available, or am I going to have to do this the hard way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132551/tool-to-merge-3-css-files

Comment: Is there an application similar to this for Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the tool **CSS Merge** for this task.

However you might see some strage stuff going on, due to the importance of styles ect.

Test it in all browsers!

Here is a link
http://www.tothepc.com/archives/combine-merge-multiple-css-files/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a source control tool such as SVN so you can merge your CSS files.

Comment: Bad idea, merge them at deployment

Comment: You need to have be in a better position than merging css during deployment time.